# Who have previously accessed a shared file?

Tags: permissions, security, users, command-history, access-control

I just discovered a mistake in the permissions setting of our system. It's kind of serious because it allows normal users to access something they shouldn't see. Currently the mistake has been fixed, but I wonder how many users have ever accessed these files. By "accessing", I mean reading from it, for example, `vi` (without saving), `less`, `cat`, `cp`, `scp`, ...

One strategy I can think of is `grep`ing through users' `~/.history` files, but they could have deleted the relevant commands.

Comment: May I ask why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't have some sort of auditing mechanism
in place at the time the file's permissions were wrong,
it's pretty much impossible. 
While your idea of searching the users' history files is not a terrible one
(if you don't have concerns over the ethical and privacy issues),
a simple `grep` won't find things like

```
cd (directory_where_file_is)
ls -l
less *
```

or cases where the user said
`vi (some_random_file)`,
and then did `:e (the_sensitive_file)`
from within `vi`.